# how to add a button at the end of the screen which contain scrollview in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created one screen with scroll view in flutter and now I want to add one button at the end of the screen but created multi times and I want only one button for whole screen.
Here in image there is more than one button and I want only one final button at the end of the screen in flutter.

[image]

I want code for adding final button at the end of scroll view screen in flutter and where to add

Comment: Please add the full widget code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PageView` instead of Scrollview:

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PageController controller = PageController();
  int _curr = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: [
          Center(
              child: Pages(
            text: "Page 1",
          )),
          Center(
              child: Pages(
            text: "Page 2",
          )),
          Center(
              child: Pages(
            text: "Page 3",
          )),
          Center(
              child: Pages(
            text: "Page 4",
          ))
        ],
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        reverse: true,
        controller: controller,
        onPageChanged: (num) {
          setState(() {
            _curr = num;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pages extends StatelessWidget {
  final text;
  Pages({this.text});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(48),
              child: Text(
                text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Text('Two rooms'),
                Text("Single bed"),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Press"),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```